# Display Android Studio GUI from Docker container while SSH tunneling through headless Ubuntu server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, x11, alpine-linux, ssh-tunnel

I have a headless Ubuntu Server (19.04) that I want to run a Docker container on that has the sole purpose running Android Studio.  The Ubuntu Server has no GUI whatsoever; it is strictly command-line only.  I'm currently on an Ubuntu VM (18.04) that is connected to the Ubuntu Server via an SSH tunnel which rides through another SSH tunnel to my Home_Router:

```
ssh admin@Home_Router -L 22222:10.0.0.2:22
ssh user@localhost -p 22222
```

The tunneling diagram is basically this:

```
     Me
 (Ubuntu_VM)                    Home_Router         Ubuntu_SVR
--------------                --------------      --------------
|            |   {INTERNET}   |            |      |            |
|            ----------------->22          |      |            |
|       22222>==============================------>22          |
|            |                |            |      |            |
--------------                --------------      --------------
                                                     10.0.0.2
```

The Docker container is based on Alpine Linux and has Android Studio installed, along with `coreutils`, `openjdk8-jre`, and `xorg-server`.  When I run the container with:

```
docker run -it -v "$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" --env DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" --net=host --rm android-studio
```

... I get the following error:

```
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

What do I need to do to forward the Android Studio GUI from the Docker container to my Ubuntu VM?  Is this possible via X11 forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out -- hopefully it helps someone else:

**Step 1: Enable X11 forwarding on the server that hosting the Docker container**

1. Make sure `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains the following line:

   ```
   X11Forwarding yes
   ```
2. `SIGHUP` `sshd` to pick up the change

   ```
   cat /var/run/sshd.pid | xargs kill -1
   ```
3. Verify `xauth` if installed on the server

   ```
   which xauth
   ```

   If it's not, then use your package manager to install it.

**Step 2: SSH into the server hosting the Docker container**

- From Linux, your `ssh` command needs to include the `-X` option.  Example:

  ```
  ssh -X user@<IP_OF_DOCKER_SERVER>
  ```
- From Windows (via PuTTY):

  - Windows needs an X server installed; install [XMing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming) and ensure it's running.
  - In PuTTY, go to 'Connection' > 'SSH' > 'X11' and check the box next to 'Enable X11 Forwarding', then connect to the server

**Step 3: Run the `docker run` command from the SSH'd terminal**

```
docker run -it --rm 
  --net=host 
  -v "$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" 
  -e DISPLAY="$DISPLAY"
  android-studio
```

---

***Note***: `xorg-server` does not need to be installed on the Docker container.